# Contar um array de uma função?

Tags: php, array

Como faço `echo` da contagem de valores do resultado da seguinte função?

```
public function get_Myinteresses() 
{
    global $db;
    $myInteresses = array();
    $get_interids = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM inter_user_conn WHERE iduser = %s", secure($this->_data['user_id'], 'int'))) or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);      
    if($get_interids->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($interids = $get_interids->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
          $nterid = $interids['idinter'];
          $get_Myinteresses = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM inter_list WHERE idinter = %s", secure($nterid, 'int') )) or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);
          if($get_Myinteresses->num_rows > 0) 
          {
              while($minteresse = $get_Myinteresses->fetch_assoc()) 
              {
                  $myInteresses[] = $minteresse;
              }
          }
        }
    }
    return $myInteresses;
}
```

Comment: Tenta `echo count(get_Myinteresses());`

Comment: Não!  Algo assim?     public function countMyint(){
      $countMyinter = count(get_Myinteresses());
      return $countMyinter;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi certo, você deveria apenas printar $get_Myinteresses->num_rows, que já retornaria a quantidade. Poderia alterar a saída para retornar a quantidade e o array para não precisar ficar calculando.

Porém, como o retorno da função é um array, você pode apenas usar a função count() no retorno da função.

```
$myInteresses =  get_Myinteresses();

$qdt = count($myInteresses);

echo $qdt;
```